# how can i solve this error in my code? TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable

Tags: python, django, search, typeerror

I'm trying to make a search function that on entering the query takes to the required result page.

But it's showing this error:
**TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable**

this my view.py code :

```
def search_result(request):
    entryList = util.list_entries
    
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    query_str = str(query)

    if query in entryList:
        query_found = True
        return render(request,"encyclopedia\search_result.html",{
            "query_found": query_found,
            "title": query,
            "content": util.get_entries(query)
        })

    else:
        query_found = False
        return render(request,"encyclopedia\search_result.html",{
            "query_found": query_found,
            "title": query,
            "search_reasult_list": entryList
        })
```

Comment: change `query` from `if query in entryList` to `query_str`

Comment: `util.list_entries` may be a function. In that case you should write `entryList=util.list_entries()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `util.list_entries` is meant to be `util.list_entries()`.

Comment: oh... I was totally focused on if statement that I didn't notice that, thanks buddy for the help